# How will I know whether my laptop computer is being shared

Tags: tcp

How will I know whether my laptop computer is being shared through TCP and IP or not been shared? What command should I look or click through? When I click the button bar for Local Area Connection Properties, it only show the General Button. By the way my computer OS is Windows XP. I appreciate if someone can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Shared? Like shared files?

An easy way might be to enable the windows-firewall and forbid all excludes.

Or you can check your "exclude" list if allowing exclusions. (Disable File-Sharing.)

Answer (score 0):

netstat will show you the connections with port numbers. If you know which port number the sharing uses you can then identify which computer is using the shares.

Answer (score 0):

Go to computer manager under Admin Tools, and have a look at the Shares section, Windows XP will have some default shares like C$ and 2 or 3 others, these are administrative shares, you remove them at your own peril, but if you are running with a blank password, or easy-to-guess password for your admin user, then it would be safer to delete these.